# How to change mat-dialog-title color based on material theme?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, sass, less

I am using **Angular Material Dialog** and trying to change the title color of the dialog dynamically according to the material theme.

```
<h1 mat-dialog-title color="primary">{{ title }}</h1>
```

It does not work, but if I set the color using css, I can change the color according to this:

```
[mat-dialog-title] {
  background: #369;
}
```

However, I need to change it as `primary`, `accent` etc. as I can apply to the mat-buttons. For this reason I tried to make some settings in the `scss` file, but I cannot change the color as `primary` via some variables (I am not sure if there is necessary variables in the `scss` file). So, how can I set the color as **primary** color of the current theme via some variables `$primary`?

Answer (score 0):

Dialog as well as others overlay styles could be updated by adding new theme class to overlay. Here is two theme, the second theme will be applied by adding class 'alternate-theme' to the root node.

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
@include mat-core();

$primary-palette: mat-palette($mat-pink, A200, 900, 50);
$accent-palette: mat-palette($mat-light-blue, 500, 900, A100);
$warn-palette: mat-palette($mat-red, 700, 900, A100);
$basic-theme: mat-dark-theme($primary-palette, $accent-palette, 
$warn-palette);
@include angular-material-theme($basic-theme);

$alt-primary-palette: mat-palette($mat-teal);
$alt-accent-palette: mat-palette($mat-pink, 600);
$alt-warn-palette: mat-palette($mat-amber, 700, 900, A100);
.alternate-theme {
  $alternate-primary: $alt-primary-palette;
  $alternate-accent: $alt-accent-palette;
  $alternate-warn: $alt-warn-palette;
  $alternate-theme: mat-light-theme($alternate-primary, $alternate-accent, $alternate-warn);
  @include angular-material-theme($alternate-theme);
}
```

But some angular components are placed separately e.g dialogs. To make it works, it is possible to apply class 'alternate-theme' to that overlay as well:

```
constructor(private overlay: OverlayContainer) {}
```

Then when switch theme

```
 switchTheme(theme: string) {
   if (theme === 'light') {
     this.overlay.getContainerElement().classList.add('alternate-theme');
   } else {
     this.overlay.getContainerElement().classList.remove('alternate-theme');
   }
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use ngStyle, if you want to change multiple things but if you just want to change color you can do something like this

```
<h1 mat-dialog-title [style.color]="myColorVar">{{ title }}</h1>
```

you can refer to this link for more detailed explanation
https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/built-in-directives/ngstyle-and-ngclass/#_ngstyle

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I need the changes accordimg to the theme that I activated. Anyway, voted up for your help.